# RTK Query Put Mutation Not Returning Data Back

Tags: redux, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-thunk, rtk-query

currently, I am implementing RTK Query. I am showing successful and error toast based on the mutation results. in my code mutation method returns an error message when the request becomes fails. but when the request becomes a success it is not returning the data object. I checked data successfully return from the backend and I also console log that data in foodApi. you can see in the update mutation I log the result. help me to find out why data is not returned from useMutation.

Also, help me to improve my code in below two situations.

1. When the request became fails in foodApi I return an empty array inside the
   query invalidtag. if I don't return an empty array then it did not
   work. that is an appropriate way to handle a situation or any other
   solution.
2. I use two useEffect functions with the different dependent
   variables. if I use one use effect then toast appears multiple times
   even if only one variable changes. Any better way to handle this
   type of situation ?

**foodApi.js:**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const foodsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "foods",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:5000/api",
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      const token = getState().user.currentUser?.token;
      if (token) {
        headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
      }
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints(builder) {
    return {
      fetchFoods: builder.query({
        providesTags: (data, error, shopId) => {
          if (error) {
            return [];
          }
          const tags = data.map((food) => {
            return { type: "Food", id: food._id };
          });
          tags.push({ type: "Shop", id: shopId });
          return tags;
        },
        query: (shopId) => {
          return {
            url: `/shop/${shopId}/foods`,
            method: "GET",
          };
        },
      }),
      addFood: builder.mutation({
        invalidatesTags: (result, error, food, arg) => {
          if (error) return [];
          return [{ type: "Shop", id: arg.shopId }];
        },
        query: (arg) => {
          return {
            url: `/shop/${arg.shopId}/foods`,
            method: "POST",
            body: arg.food,
          };
        },
      }),
      updateFood: builder.mutation({
        invalidatesTags: (result, error, food) => {
          console.log(result);
          if (error) return [];
          return [{ type: "Food", id: food._id }];
        },
        query: (food) => {
          return {
            url: `/food/${food._id}`,
            method: "PUT",
            body: food,
          };
        },
      }),
      removeFood: builder.mutation({
        invalidatesTags: (result, error, food) => {
          if (error) return [];
          return [{ type: "Food", id: food._id }];
        },
        query: (food) => {
          return {
            method: "DELETE",
            url: `/food/${food._id}`,
          };
        },
      }),
    };
  },
});

export const {
  useUpdateFoodMutation,
  useRemoveFoodMutation,
  useFetchFoodsQuery,
  useAddFoodMutation,
} = foodsApi;
export { foodsApi };
```

**FoodBox.jsx:**

```
function FoodBox({ food }) {

  const [updateFood,{data:updateSuccess,error:updateError}] = useUpdateFoodMutation();
  const [removeFood,{data:deleteSuccess,error:deleteError}] = useRemoveFoodMutation();
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser);
  const handleFoodUpdate = () => {
    updateFood({ ...food, isVisible: !food.isVisible });
  };

  const handleFoodDelete = () => {
    removeFood(food);
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(updateError) {
      toast.error(updateError.data);
    }
    if(updateSuccess) {
      toast.success('Food Updated Successfully');
    }
  },[updateError,updateSuccess]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(deleteError) {
      toast.error(deleteError.data);
    }
    if(deleteSuccess) {
      toast.success('Food Deleted Successfully');
    }
  },[deleteError,deleteSuccess]);

  return (
    <Box>
      <PairContainer>
        {user && <CheckBox
          type="checkbox"
          checked={food.isVisible}
          onChange={handleFoodUpdate}
        /> }
        <FoodDetail>{food.name} </FoodDetail>
      </PairContainer>
      <PairContainer>
        <Price>
          <MdCurrencyRupee />
          {food.price}
        </Price>
        {user && <DeleteIcon onClick={handleFoodDelete}>
          <MdDelete />
        </DeleteIcon>}
      </PairContainer>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default FoodBox;
```